# TDD ...how?

Tags: tdd

I'm about to start out my first TDD (test-driven development) program, and I (naturally) have a TDD mental block..so I was wondering if someone could help guide me on where I should start a bit.

I'm creating a function that will read binary data from socket and parses its data into a class object.

As far as I see, there are 3 parts:

1) Logic to parse data
2) socket class
3) class object

What are the steps that I should take so that I could incrementally TDD? I definitely plan to first write the test before even implementing the function.

Comment: To do hands-on practice katas, refer: https://github.com/garora/TDD-Katas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue in TDD is "design for testability"

First, you must have an interface against which to write tests.

To get there, you must have a rough idea of what your testable units are.

1. Some class, which is built by a function.
2. Some function, which reads from a socket and emits a class.

Second, given this rough interface, you formalize it into actual non-working class and function definitions.

Third, you start to write your tests -- knowing they'll compile but fail.

Part-way through this, you may start head-scratching about your function.  How do you set up a socket for your function?  That's a pain in the neck.

However, the interface you roughed out above isn't the law, it's just a good idea.  What if your function took an array of bytes and created a class object?  This is much, much easier to test.

So, revisit the steps, change the interface, write the non-working class and function, now write the tests.

Now you can fill in the class and the function until all your tests pass.

When you're done with this bit of testing, all you have to do is hook in a real socket.  Do you trust the socket libraries?  (Hint: you should)  Not much to test here.  If you don't trust the socket libraries, now you've got to provide a source for the data that you can run in a controlled fashion.  That's a large pain.

Answer (score 5):

Your split sounds reasonable. I would consider the two dependencies to be the input and output. Can you make them less dependent on concrete production code? For instance, can you make it read from a general stream of data instead of a socket? That would make it easier to pass in test data.

The creation of the return value could be harder to mock out, and may not be a problem anyway - is the logic used for the actual population of the resulting object reasonably straightforward (after the parsing)? For instance, is it basically just setting trivial properties? If so, I wouldn't bother trying to introduce a factory etc there - just feed in some test data and check the results.

Answer (score 4):

First, start thinking "the testS", plural, rather than "the test", singular. You should expect to write more than one.

Second, if you have mental block, consider starting with a simpler challenge. Lower the difficulty until it's real easy to do, then move on to more substantial work.

For instance, assume you already have a byte array with the binary data, so you don't even need to think about sockets. All you need to write is something that takes in a byte[] and return an instance of your object. Can you write a test for that ?

If you still have mental block, lower it yet another notch. Assume your byte array is only going to contain default values anyway. So you don't even have to worry about the parsing, just about being able to return an instance of your object that has all values set to the defaults. Can you write a test for that ?

I imagine something like:

```
public void testFooReaderCanParseDefaultFoo() {
  FooReader fr = new FooReader();
  Foo myFoo = fr.buildFoo();
  assertEquals(0, myFoo.bar());
}
```

That's rock bottom, right ? You're only testing the Foo constructor. But you can then move up to the next level:

```
public void testFooReaderGivenBytesBuildsFoo() {
  FooReader fr = new FooReader();
  byte[] fooData = {1};
  fr.consumeBytes(fooData);
  Foo myFoo = fr.buildFoo();
  assertEquals(1, myFoo.bar());
}
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2):

'The best testing framework is the application itself'

I believe that a common misconception amongst developers is, they mistakenly make a strong association between testing frameworks and TDD principles. I would advise re-reading the official docs on TDD; bearing in mind that, there is no real relationship between testing frameworks and TDD. After all, TDD is a paradigm not a framework.

Upon reading the wiki on TDD (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), I've come to realise that to an extent things are a little bit open to interpretation.

There are various personal styles of TDD mainly due to the fact that TDD principles are open to interpretation.

I'm not here to say anyone is wrong, but I would like to share my techniques with you and explain how they have served me well. Bear in mind that I have been programming for 36 years; making my programming habits very well evolved.

1. Code reuse is over rated. Reuse code too much and you'll end up with bad abstraction and it will become very difficult to fix or change something without it affecting something else. The obvious advantage being less code to manage.
2. Repeating too much code leads to code management problems and oversized code bases. However it does have the advantage of good separation of concerns (the ability to tweak, change and fix things without affecting other parts of the app).
3. Don't repeat/refactor too much, don't reuse too much. Code needs to be maintainable. It’s important to understand and respect the balance between code reuse and abstraction/separation of concerns.

When deciding whether to reuse code I base the decision on: .... Will the nature of this code change in context throughout the app codebase? If the answer is no, then I reuse it. If the answer is yes or I'm not sure, I repeat/refactor it. I will however revise my codebases from time to time and see if any of my repeated code can be merged without compromising separation of concerns/abstraction.

As far as my basic programming habits are concerned, I like to write the conditions (if then else switch case etc) first; test them, then fill the conditions with the code and test again. Keep in mind there's no rule that you have to do this in a unit test. I refer to this as the low level stuff.
Once my low level stuff is done, I'll either reuse the code or refactor it into another part of the app, but not after testing it very thoroughly. Problem with repeating/refactoring badly tested code is that, if it’s broken, you have to fix it in multiple places.

BDD To me is a natural follow on from TDD. Once my code base is well tested I can easily tweak behaviours by moving entire blocks of code around. Cool thing is about my programming habits is that sometimes I move code around and discover useful behaviours that I didn’t even intend. It can sometimes even be useful for rebranding stuff to seem like a completely different code base.

To this end my code bases tend to start out a bit slow and pick up momentum because as I advance toward the end of development I have more and more code to refactor from or reuse.

The advantages for me in the way that I code is that, I am able to take on very high levels of complexity as this is promoted by good separation of concerns. It’s also awesome for writing highly optimised code. However the well optimised code tends to be a bit bloated, but to my knowledge there is no way to write optimized code without a bit of bloating. If the app doesn't need high processor efficiency, there's nothing stopping me from de-bloating my code. I'm of the opinion that server side code should be optimised and most client side code normally doesn't require it.

Going back to the topic of testing frameworks, I use them to just save a bit of compiler time.

As far as following story boards is concerned, that comes naturally to me without actually considering it. I've noticed most devs develop in the natural order of story boards even when they are not available.

As a general separation of concerns strategy, in most apps I separate concerns based on UI forms. For example I’ll reuse code within a form and repeat/refactor across forms. This is only a generalistic rule. There are times when I have to think outside the box. Sometimes repeating code can serve well for making code processor efficient.

As a little addendum to my TDD habits; I do optimizations and fault tolerance last. I will try to avoid using try catch blocks as much as possible and write my code in such a way as to not need them. For example rather than catch a null, I will check for null, or rather than catch an index out of bounds, I will scrutinise my code so that it never happens. I find that error trapping too early in app development, leads to semantic errors (behavioural errors that don't crash the app). Semantic errors can be very hard to trace or even notice.
Well that’s my 10 cents. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Test Driven Development ?
So, this means you should start with writing a test first.

Write a test which contains the code like 'how you want to use your class'.  This class or method that you are going to test with this test, is not even there yet.

For instance, you could write a test first like this:

```
[Test]
public void CanReadDataFromSocket()
{
     SocketReader r = new SocketReader( ... ); // create a socketreader instance which takes a socket or a mock-socket in its constructor

     byte[] data = r.Read();

     Assert.IsTrue (data.Length > 0);
}
```

For instance; I'm just making up an example here.
Next, once you're able to read data from a socket, you can start thinking on how you'll parse it, and write a test in where you use the 'Parser' class which takes the data that you've read, and outputs an instance of your data class.
etc...

Comment: Agree with the first two sentence, but what's about assertation? An AAA example would be better, I think.

Comment: Yes indeed; defenitly, you have to test in your test whether or not the results are as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing where to start writing tests and when to stop writing tests while using TDD, is a common problem when starting out.

I have found that it can sometimes help to write an **integration test** first. Doing so will help create some of the common objects you will be using. It will also allow you to focus your thoughts and tests, since you will need to start writing tests to make the integration test pass.

Answer (score 0):

When I was starting with TDD, I read these 3 rules by Uncle Bob that really helped me out:

> 1. You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to
>      make a failing unit test pass.
> 2. You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail; and compilation failures are failures.
> 3. You are not allowed to write any more production code than is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test.

In a shorter version it would be:

> 1. Write only enough of a unit test to fail.
> 2. Write only enough production code to make the failing unit test pass.

as you can see, this is very simple.